# How to find trendline without graphing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, trendlines

I have set of data in Excel for which I would like to find the trendline. Is there a way to find the trendline (linear and non-linear) from the raw data? Or do I have to graph the data and use the graph's trendline tool?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have data in columns **A** and **B** like:

[image]

To do a linear trend we need a *slope* and *intercept*.  In **D2** enter:

```
=SLOPE(B2:B20,A2:A20)
```

and in **E2** enter:

```
=INTERCEPT(B2:B20,A2:A20)
```

[image]

There are equally simple formulas to get the parameters of other non-linear fits such as higher order polynomials, etc.

Comment: I understand, but does no function exist to directly call upon Excel's trendline-finding capability?

Comment: @techSultan  these are the trending functions

Comment: So I must do the Linear Algebra for higher order polynomials and exponentials myself in Excel. I can't just call a function polyFit([data range], order of poly).

Thanks